# Why Windows NFS Client Still Connects TCP 139&445?

Tags: windows, networking, nfs, network-attached-storage

I setup my Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 as NFS client, and mounted a NFS share from external storage array with -anon option. Sometimes it has a delay at 99%, and then finished. From Wireshark, I can see although it used 2049(NFS) to transfer the data, the clients still tried to connect to port 139(NETBIOS) and 445(SMB/CIFS), the external storage did not listen the ports, so it rejected and caused the delay. My question is why it still uses TCP 139 and 445 besides of 2049?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. In almost any case I have seen this delay, it is the applications (app that access the share) fault. Windows just maps the share to a drive, but a *lot* of apps try to access it the good old UNC way, which triggers the CIFS client to try it first.

Word (2010) for example does not (voluntary) store files on R:\, for example, but on \server\ressource. You can see this when debugging the file and search vor UNC references (like 'last print settings' oder 'tmp file remove'), they will all point to the UNC one. I have no idead where this legacy bahaviour comes from, but apps doing this mostly use the win32 API.

The NFS Client itself does not show this behaviour, or I was just never able to reproduce it.